# "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" assigning to an index in an empty list

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

```
#all leter are MAG
#E->3 A->4 O->0 V->W I->2
#rand ASCII with ch
from random import randint
letterNum=randint(4,8)
word=[]
if len(word)==0:
  faseLetter=chr(randint(65,90))
  word[0]=faseLetter
  voc=['A','E','O','U','Y','I']
for i in range (letterNum+1):
  firstLetter=word[letterNum]
  randomChangeMaker=randint(1,2)
  if firstLetter in ['A','E','O','U','Y','I']:
    faseLetter=chr(randint((66,68),(70,72),(74,78),(80,88),(90)))
    if faseLetter == 'W' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='V'
  else:
    faseLetter=chr(randint(65,90))
    if faseLetter == 'E' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='3'
    elif faseLetter == 'A' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='4'
    elif faseLetter == 'O' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
     faseLetter='0'
    elif faseLetter == 'V' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='W'
    elif faseLetter == 'W' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='V'
    elif faseLetter == 'I' and randomChangeMaker == 2:
      faseLetter='2'
  word=word+faseLetter
print(word)
```

**that's my code and I'm getting this error(I'm using replit.com editor)**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 10, in 
word[0]=faseLetter
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: The title should describe your specific problem, not just say what construct you were working with when you encountered it. I've edited towards that end.

Comment: For future reference, you can help us help you by creating a minimum working example that demonstrates what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be shorted to

```
>>> word = []
>>> word[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

From [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

```
s[i] = x      item i of s is replaced by x
```

The key here is "replaced". The item has to exist to be replaced. instead, you can append

```
word.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `word` is empty, so you can't assign anything to its zeroth member since there is no such member. (JavaScript might let you do this, but that's JavaScript for you, eh?)

Either:

1. `word.append(faseLetter)` to the empty list instead of `word[0] = faseLetter`, so it becomes a list of length 1
2. Initialize `word` with a "fake" zeroth member, i.e. `word = [None]` instead of `word = []` so you can assign to that zeroth member.

Answer (score 0):

What's the length of the array word?
referring to line 10 you said word[0]=faseletter..
but since you didn't initiate the array word size then you can't do that.
You have to use append in this case.

Comment: This is not an answer, please consider to put you thoughts in question comments.

Answer (score 0):

Get these clear.

**letterNum** is being assigned a value between 4 to 8.

**word.append(faseLetter)** is appending one letter at **0th** index.

in **for loop** `firstLetter=word[letterNum]` (Considering letterNum is between 4-8) it will always give error as length of list **word** is just one and **word[letterNum]** is trying to get element form index which does not exit.

```
faseLetter=chr(randint((66,68),(70,72),(74,78),(80,88),(90)))
```

will give error as following

> randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 6 were given

Because

> random.randint only takes two arguments, a start and an end. The third
> argument mentioned by Python is self, which is done automatically.

Comment: where is `voc=['A','E','O','U','Y','I']` is being used ? Can you signify it's purpose.